# Why do compact groups have only countably many irreducible representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, compactness

I read that for a compact Hausdorff group $G$, the set $\hat{G}$ of isomorphism classes of irreducible unitary representations of $G$ is countable. Why is this the case?

Comment: I don't believe this. What about an uncountable direct product of finite groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use the following fact: if $G$ is a locally compact topological group that is second-countable, then $L^2(G)$ is a separable Hilbert space, and in fact this holds for all $L^p$, $p\geq 1$ as explained in this [MO answer of Dmitri Pavlov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable). In fact second-countability is necessary as well according to his answer.

Now if $G$ is in addition compact,the Peter-Weyl theorem says that the matrix coefficients of finite-dimensional unitary irreducible representations are an orthonormal basis of $L^2(G)$, and that every irreducible unitary representation is finite-dimensional. Now your claim follows from the fact. It would seem in the comments there's a counterexample when $G$ is not second-countable.